# Simulink escape with delete_block

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

I'm trying to used MATLAB delete_block function, which given a simulink block path deletes the block.
Unfortunately if the name of the block includes a `/` it is unable to delete the block because of `/` escaping.
If for example the full path is:

```
system/subsystem/outputBlock[rad/s]
```

`delete_block` fails deleting the block (without reporting any failure).
In a warning message, which is not generated by the the delete_block function, I spotted that the path of the block is reported to be:
`system/subsystem/outputBlock[rad//s]` (with the last `/` escaped).
So probably what happens is that the path is escaped and is not found since instead of searching for `system/subsystem/outputBlock[rad/s]`, `delete_block` searches for `system/subsystem/outputBlock[rad//s]`.
To verify this, I tried by changing the name of the block manually by removing the last `/` and the `delete_block` function works.
How can I delete blocks whose name in the pathname includes a `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope, I can help here.  The `//` is the escape sequence for the `/` character.  If you want to delete blocks with the `//` in the name, I think it best to recurse down the tree to get the fully qualified name and escape any `/` at each point.

```
% get the name of the block you want to delete, we'll just use gcb() for now
blk = gcb;
nameList = {};
% get the name of this block
currBlk = get_param(blk,'Name')
nameList{end+1} = currBlk;
% get the name of the root block diagram
rootName = bdroot(blk)
while( ~strcmp(get_param(blk,'Parent'),rootName) )
  currBlk = get_param(blk,'Parent');
  nameList{end+1} = get_param(currBlk,'Name');
end
nameList{end+1} = rootName;
% for completeness, here's a naive attempt to reconstruct the path
str='';
for ii=length(nameList):-1:1
  str = [str strrep(nameList{ii},'/','//') '/' ];
end
str(end) = []; % get rid of the last '/'
```

HTH!